# Manage flick event in pivot in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a pivot and it contains images. I have to make pinch zoom functionality in it. For that I took viewport and a canvas and inside it put the images. I am able to zoom the images. But I have problem with flick the images. When I am flicking the images images are scrolling, but I want that if user flick next image of pivot should come.And when images are zoomed then it should not be flicked.How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the behavior [Pinch Zoom images bound in Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316302/pinch-zoom-images-bound-in-listbox/15134062#15134062) for pinch to zoom functionality. After that in the code behind, register the flick event, in that test the transform values of image, if there is no change to these values allow the event, else hold the event by handling it.